# Is there any R function to extract all taxonomy name (phylum, class, order, family ...) from species taxonomic ID/ species name or genus name?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, ncbi, ropensci

I have the taxonomic ID of species and I can get the species and genus name from NCBI (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/TaxIdentifier/tax_identifier.cgi). But I want phylum, class, order.. all from these data.

I have tried [taxize package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=taxize), but not working for a large dataset.

```
specieslist <- c("Clostridium", "Clostridium",  "Achromobacter",    "Achromobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Acinetobacter",    "Actinomyces",  "Actinomyces",  "Aeromonas",    "Agrococcus",   "Alcanivorax",  "Alkalihalobacillus",   "Alloprevotella",   "Aminobacterium",   "Amniculibacterium",    "Anaerocolumna",    "Anaerocolumna",    "Anaerocolumna",    "Asticcacaulis",    "Atopobium",    "Bacillus", "Bacillus", "Bacteroidales",    "Bacteroides",  "Bacteroides",  "Bacteroides",  "Bacteroides",  "Bacteroides",  "Bacteroides",  "Barnesiella",  "Bifidobacterium",  "Blochmannia",  "Bordetella",   "Brevibacillus",    "Buchnera", "Burkholderia", "Butyricimonas",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Campylobacter",    "Capnocytophaga",   "Capnocytophaga",   "Capnocytophaga",   "Chroococcidiopsis",    "Citrobacter",  "Clostridium",  "Clostridium",  "Clostridium",  "Clostridium",  "Corynebacterium",  "Corynebacterium",  "Corynebacterium",  "Corynebacterium",  "Cutibacterium",    "Dialister",    "Dolosigranulum",   "Enterobacter", "Enterococcus", "Entomoplasma", "Escherichia",  "Escherichia",  "Escherichia",  "Eubacterium",  "Fermentimonas",    "Frankia",  "Fusobacterium",    "Fusobacterium",    "Fusobacterium",    "Fusobacterium",    "Fusobacterium",    "Fusobacterium",    "Gemella",  "Haemophilus",  "Haemophilus",  "Halomonas",    "Hydrogenophaga",   "Ilyobacter",   "Klebsiella",   "Klebsiella",   "Klebsiella",   "Klebsiella",   "Klebsiella",   "Kocuria",  "Kytococcus",   "Lachnoanaerobaculum",  "Lachnospira",  "Lachnospiraceae",  "Lachnospiraceae",  "Lacrimispora", "Lactobacillus",    "Lactobacillus",    "Lactobacillus",    "Lactobacillus",    "Lactobacillus",    "Lancefieldella",   "Lautropia",    "Leptotrichia", "Leptotrichia", "Leptotrichia", "Leptotrichia", "Leptotrichia", "Leptotrichia", "Leptotrichia", "Leptotrichia", "Ligilactobacillus",    "Limosilactobacillus",  "Luteimonas",   "Lysinibacillus",   "Lysobacter",   "Lysobacter",   "Lysobacter",   "Magnetospirillum", "Marivirga",    "Megasphaera",  "Megasphaera",  "Meiothermus",  "Methylobacterium", "Methylobacterium", "Methylobacterium", "Methylobacterium", "Methylobacterium", "Microbacterium",   "Microbacterium",   "Microbacterium",   "Microbacterium",   "Micrococcus",  "Muribaculaceae",   "Muribaculum",  "Muribaculum",  "Neisseria",    "Neisseria",    "Neisseria",    "Neisseria",    "Neisseria",    "Neisseria",    "Neisseria",    "Nocardioides", "Nocardioides", "Paludibacter", "Pantoea",  "Paracoccus",   "Paracoccus",   "Paraprevotella",   "Pasteurella",  "Petrimonas",   "Phenylobacterium", "Phocaeicola",  "Phocaeicola",  "Phocaeicola",  "Phyllobacterium",  "Polaribacter", "Pontibacter",  "Pontibacter",  "Porphyromonas",    "Porphyromonas",    "Porphyromonas",    "Porphyromonas",    "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Prevotella",   "Proteus",  "Pseudoleptotrichia",   "Pseudomonas",  "Pseudonocardia",   "Pseudonocardia",   "Raoultella",   "Rheinheimera", "Romboutsia",   "Roseivirga",   "Roseococcus",  "Rothia",   "Rothia",   "Rubrobacter",  "Rubrobacter",  "Rufibacter",   "Saccharomonospora",    "Saccharopolyspora",    "Saccharopolyspora",    "Salinivirga",  "Salmonella",   "Schaalia", "Sedimentisphaera", "Selenomonas",  "Selenomonas",  "Selenomonas",  "Selenomonas",  "Selenomonas",  "Selenomonas",  "Shigella", "Skermanella",  "Sphingosinicella", "Spirosoma",    "Staphylococcus",   "Staphylococcus",   "Stenotrophomonas", "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptococcus",    "Streptomyces", "Tannerella",   "Tannerella",   "Thermovirga",  "Treponema",    "Treponema",    "Treponema",    "Treponema",    "Treponema",    "Treponema",    "Veillonella",  "Veillonella",  "Veillonella",  "Veillonella",  "Veillonella")


t <- tax_name(query = c(specieslist), get = c("phylum","class", "order", "family", "genus"), db = "ncbi")
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2):

(`taxize` maintainer here)

Another option if `taxize` is too slow for you is `taxizedb`. By default uses NCBI as the data source. `taxizedb` is similar to `taxize`, but uses local database dumps instead of doing http requests; but you do have the initial setup time to download databases

```
install.packages("taxizedb")
library(taxizedb)
ids <- name2taxid(x, out_type="summary")
classification(ids$id)
```

Then you can pull out whatever ranks you want from each data.frame

Answer (score 0):

https://bioinf.shenwei.me/taxonkit/usage/#usage-and-examples

```
taxonkit lineage txtid.txt | tee lineage.txt

cat lineage.txt \
    | taxonkit reformat \
    | csvtk -H -t cut -f 1,3 \
    | csvtk -H -t sep -f 2 -s ';' -R \
    | csvtk add-header -t -n taxid,kindom,phylum,class,order,family,genus,species \
    | csvtk pretty -t
```